# Why motor Speed variation is irregular

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I  was making a [motor animation in Blender](https://github.com/kebab03/motorDOute).

At some point I notice that with the give setting the cube initially speed up  and then slow down, which is not expected.

What is the reason of this behavior?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: I think i was explaing as much as i could ,file link was to have the real model to see what was happenings.

Comment: It slows down because you keyframed the [*Target Velocity*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.3/physics/rigid_body/constraints/types/motor.html). If you remove the keyframe and set the value to a constant number, the rotation will be accelerated and the speed will be maintained until the end of the animation.

Comment: @Blunder maybe write this answer so that he's informed